# Ubuntu 20.04/22.04 instalación de webmin y otros componentes

Tags: ubuntu, apache

Tal vez este no es el lugar indicado para hacer la pregunta, pero...

Tras un problema con un proveedor de hosting, he decidido abrir otro servidor para tenerlo mientras solucionan la incidencia en el servidor principal, la cosa es que he probado tanto con Ubuntu 22.04 como con Ubuntu 20.04 y con ambos me dan problemas los puertos del servidor.

He instalado Webmin siguiendo miles de tutoriales (Digital Ocean, ChatGPT, videos, a mi manera, con la documentación oficial), todos esos tutoriales hacen que se instale y cuando hago **sudo systemctl status webmin** me indica que está activo y funcionando (active (running)) pero a pesar de abrir el puerto con UFW o incluso desactivarlo y abrir el puerto 10000 en el hosting, no consigo conectarme.

También he probado con Apache y ni siquiera consigo ver la página por defecto de instalación a pesar de que me indica que también está activo y funcionando.

¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando? Es la última versión de Ubuntu 20.04 y 22.04 y me lleva ocurriendo en los 3 servidores que he probado.

Canonical-Ubuntu-20.04-aarch64-2023.09.28-0
Canonical-Ubuntu-22.04-aarch64-2023.09.27-0

Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme!